# Gravity from algebra

Tags: gravity, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, poincare-symmetry

Can someone provide me a reference that describes the gauging of the Poincare algebra to obtain Einstein's relativity?

> "It is well known that Einstein’s formulation of gravity can be obtained by performing a formal gauging procedure of the Poincare algebra. In this procedure one associates a gauge field with each generator of the Poincare algebra. Next, one imposes constraints on the curvature tensors of these gauge fields such that the translational symmetries of the algebra get converted into general coordinate transformations. At the same time the gauge field of the Lorentz transformations gets expressed into (derivatives of) the Vierbein gauge field which is the only independent gauge field. One thus obtains an off-shell formulation of Einstein gravity. On-shell Einstein gravity is obtained by imposing the usual Einstein equations of motion." - Eric Bergshoeff

Comment: If you are interested in the historical development rather than the physics as such, you might also consider asking at [hsm.SE] instead.